# Editing post in admin panel

Tags: admin, post-meta, front-end

I have a front end posting form. Everythings work nice, but the custom (meta) fields i added in the form doesn't appear in admin panel post edit? I add them with add_post_meta() function. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the relevant portions of your code?

Comment: It's a lot of code separate in few files. Actually, the things that are happening are pretty simple: First a simple html form, next I get the data via $_POST global variable and then pass it to add_post_meta function. That's it.

Comment: _"I add them with add_post_meta() function."_ - you should at least post that portion.

Comment: `$price = $_POST['price'];
add_post_meta($pid, 'car_price', $price, true);`

Comment: No one knows here?

Comment: You're really not giving enough to work with. [Have a read of this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What i am asking, is a mechanical way my custom fields (meta boxes) to appear in admin editing area.